# merging data from two spreadsheets together

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two spreadsheets, one with data listed against a product identified by the style (sku), the second spreadsheet has the different product colour and size options for each sku. I want to merge the two spreadsheets together so that I have all of the colour and size variations for each sku as well as all of the details that are matched to the sku i.e. long description, product name, catalogue etc... I am trying to do this in excel

Comment: Are you trying to do this for a report, or create a brand new 'standalone' workbook with both tables merged?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant details on your existing setup as well as what methods you've already tried to achieve your desired results

Answer (score 1):

## Starting point

Two existing spreadsheets:

- `products.xlsx`, with two columns:

  - Product name
  - SKU code
- `sku.xlsx`, with five columns

  - SKU code
  - Colour
  - Size
  - Long description
  - Release year

In reality you can have any arbitrary number of columns, as long as there's 1 identifying column that appears in both spreadsheets  (in this example `SKU code`).

[image]

## Solution 1: [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

This is the easiest, but is not very flexible and can be slow on many rows.

1. Open both Excel files
2. In the `products` file, write the following formula in cell `C2`:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, [sku.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$E$4, 2, 0)
```

- `B2`: It looks up the SKU code in `B2`
- `[sku.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$E$4`: finds that value in the leftmost column of the range defined in this argument<sup>1</sup>.
- `2`: it then takes the matching value from the 2nd column of that range (column `Colour` in the `sku` file)
- `0`: indicates that you want an exact match

3. In the `products` file drag the formula in  `C2` down.
4. In cell `D2`, copy the formula from cell `C2`, but now lookup the 3rd column instead of the 2nd by changing the 3rd VLOOKUP argument from `2` to `3`.
5. Drag it down
6. Repeat for remaining columns if necessary

This is how the `products` file looks:

[image]

And these are the underlying formulas, I've highlighted the argument that changes to get other columns:

[image]

## Solution 2: [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) & [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

For flexibility and speed the real pro's use this method. It requires a bit more steps though.

1. Open both Excel files
2. In the `products` file, write the following formula in cell `C2`:

```
=INDEX([sku.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$E$4, MATCH(B2, [sku.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4, 0), 2)
```

- INDEX

  - `[sku.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$E$4`: this is the range that contains all data you want to lookup. It can include the identification column, but it's not necessary<sup>1</sup>.
  - `MATCH` - This argument should have the row number. It's found with the MATCH function

    - `B2`: this is the value MATCH will be looking for
    - `[sku.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4`: this is the range it will be looking in<sup>1</sup>.
    - `0`: indicates you want an exact match
  - `2`: The column number of the range from where the value should be retrieved. In this case I chose `2` as that's the `Colour` column in the `sku` file.

3. In the `products` file drag the formula in  `C2` down.
4. In cell `D2`, copy the formula from cell `C2`, but now lookup the 3rd column instead of the 2nd by changing the last INDEX argument from `2` to `3`.
5. Drag it down
6. Repeat for remaining columns if necessary

This is how the `products` file looks (same as with VLOOKUP):

[image]

And these are the underlying formulas, I've highlighted the argument that changes to get other columns:

[image]

---

**Footnotes**
<sub>1: Make sure this range is an absolute definition (using `$` for row and column) such that it does not shift when you drag the formula down.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Consolidate Data**. Excel can merge data from different spreadsheets (worksheets) or different files. Another thing you can do is use a **Pivot Table**.

For Consolidation, read this [support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214270) from **Microsoft**.

For Pivot Tables, you can read [this question in **Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636802/how-to-conditionally-merge-join-excel-worksheets) which has a good example and also has another alternative (by using **SQL**) to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Please don't answer with "go read this link". If that link ever changes or stop working your answer will become useless, especially for links beyond control of StackExchange network. Please post relevant portions from that link directly in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vlookup() function in your second worksheet to merge its data with the data from your first sheet. You can google for more information about the syntax of the vlookup function or find more details here:
http://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2011/12/14/lookup-excel-functions-vlookup/

If it is a one-time task and you don't have time to learn vlookup(), install the Merge Tables Wizard add-in (it is commercial, but a fully-functional 15-day trial version is available), you can download it here: 
http://www.ablebits.com/excel-lookup-tables/index.php

If you opt for the Merge Tables wizard, be sure to choose your SECOND worksheet with colour and size variations as the Main table. Merging 2 tables will take you about 5 min with the add-in installation.